# Offseting and copying a cell value by getting its reference from another cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I m trying to read a cell's value from by offset a cell reference which is read as value of another cell.

What I have tried is below:

```
  wb.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E7").Value.Offset(0, -1).Select).Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

wb is a workbook from another file. Cell E7 has a reference as text value and after offset it gives another cell's ref in the wb workbook.

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.select`? And the `.value`.

Comment: Of Course does not work!

Comment: explain in detail what doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E7").Value).Offset(0, -1).Copy
```

You were missing a closing paranthesis after `.Value`

Say the content of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E7").Value` is `B1:B4`, the above line will copy `wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A4")`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the value, avoid copy/paste and set the two ranges equal

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E8") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("E7").Offset(0, -1)
```

Comment: E7 is a cell in Current Workbook that contains a reference of another cell.
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E7").Offset(0, -1) is Wrong to refer to in wb.

Comment: Then remove `wb.Sheets(1)`.  You can't have both.